# What is the ideal way of solving the following error?

Tags: rust, operator-overloading

What is the ideal way of solving the following error?

- Should I modify the overloaded operator?
- Should I modify the reference/pointer values?

```
use std::ops::Add;

pub struct Vec3
{
    pub x: f64,
    pub y: f64,
    pub z: f64
}

impl Add for Vec3
{
    type Output = Vec3;
    fn add(self, other: Vec3) -> Vec3
    {
        Vec3
        {
            x: self.x + other.x,
            y: self.y + other.y,
            z: self.z + other.z
        }
    }
}

impl Vec3
{
    pub fn apply_by_value__mbr(mut self, rhs:Vec3)
    {
        self = self + rhs;
    }
    pub fn apply_by_ref__mbr(mut self, rhs: &Vec3)
    {
        self = self + *rhs;
    }
    pub fn apply_by_value__st(lhs: Vec3, rhs:Vec3) -> Vec3
    {
        let mut temp: Vec3;
        temp = lhs + rhs;
        return temp;
    }
    pub fn apply_by_ref__st(v1: &Vec3, v2: &Vec3) -> Vec3
    {
        return v1 + v2;
    }
    pub fn print(self)
    {
        println!("x:{}, y:{}, z:{}", self.x, self.y, self.z);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
PS C:\git\Rust examples\operator_overloading> cargo build
   Compiling operator_overloading_lib v0.1.0 (C:\git\Rust examples\operator_overloading)                                                                                                     
error[E0369]: cannot add `&Vec3` to `&Vec3`                                                                                                                                                  
  --> src\vec3.rs:42:19                                                                                                                                                                      
   |                                                                                                                                                                                         
42 |         return v1 + v2;                                                                                                                                                                 
   |                -- ^ -- &Vec3                                                                                                                                                            
   |                |                                                                                                                                                                        
   |                &Vec3                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                             
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0369`.                                                                                                                          
error: could not compile `operator_overloading_lib` due to previous error
PS C:\git\Rust examples\operator_overloading>
```

Comment: `impl<'a> Add for &'a Vec3`

Comment: `**rhs` should just be `*rhs`, or you can introduce `impl<'a> Add<&'a Vec3> for Vec3` as well

Comment: @PitaJ, ok. what about the other one?

Comment: @PitaJ, i am trying to understand operator overloading.

Comment: Please keep the content on here professional... Just cause you don'- see a reason doesn't mean there isn't one.

Comment: The probably downvoted because your question includes practically zero context on what you're trying to accomplish. Please try to do better in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should make `Vec3` a copyable type. This makes working with it much easier and simplifies our implementations below.

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct Vec3 {
    pub x: f64,
    pub y: f64,
    pub z: f64,
}
```

You should probably have an impl for each permutation of `Vec3` and `&Vec3`:

```rust
// This is the same as `impl Add for Vec3`.
// The trait `Add` has an optional generic parameter,
// which defaults to the type it's implemented for.
//
// I write it out explicitly so you can see each permutation.
impl Add<Vec3> for Vec3 {
    type Output = Vec3;
    fn add(self, other: Vec3) -> Vec3 {
        Vec3 {
            x: self.x + other.x,
            y: self.y + other.y,
            z: self.z + other.z,
        }
    }
}

impl Add<&Vec3> for &Vec3 {
    type Output = Vec3;
    fn add(self, other: &Vec3) -> Vec3 {
        *self + *other
    }
}

impl Add<Vec3> for &Vec3 {
    type Output = Vec3;
    fn add(self, other: Vec3) -> Vec3 {
        *self + other
    }
}

impl Add<&Vec3> for Vec3 {
    type Output = Vec3;
    fn add(self, other: &Vec3) -> Vec3 {
        self + *other
    }
}
```

Also FYI: standard formatting of Rust code puts the opening curly brace on the same line.

---

Edit: here's how you might implement `Add` for a generic-sized vector:

```rust
pub struct Vector<const N: usize> {
    pub dims: [f64; N],
}

impl<const N: usize>  std::ops::Add for &Vector<N> {
    type Output = Vector<N>;
    fn add(self, other: Self) -> Self::Output {
        // Make copy
        let mut dims = self.dims.clone();
        // Add each element in `other`
        for (a, b) in dims.iter_mut().zip(other.dims.iter()) {
            *a += b;
        }
        
        // Return new instance
        Vector { dims }
    }
}
```

Do note that passing one of these with hundreds or thousands of dimensions on the stack can be expensive and it might be better to put them inside a `Box`.

Comment: *First of all, you should make Vec3 a copyable type. This makes working with it much easier and simplifies our implementations below.* - What if the vector is 100000 elements long? If I copy a vector each time, would it be efficient?

Comment: Yes if you plan on making vectors of that size, they should probably not be `Copy`. In that case, you should probably only have a single case: `impl Add for &Vector`

Comment: So, please update your answer.